# X-path is not working for multiple html tags on one page

Tags: html, xpath, iframe

I have written below x-path for finding an element uniquely

```
(//div[contains(@id,'30425580') and contains(@arvisibility,'visible')])//div[contains(@id,'1000000422')]/div/a[2]
```

It was working fine when there was only one HTML flow. But now I can see 3 HTML tags on same form and my current XPath is not able to find the element.

I tried with `(//div[contains(@id,'30425580') and contains(@arvisibility,'visible')])//iframe`

but beyond this I am not able to traverse as `#document`  tag is there.
and my dive is inside this **HTML**.

Comment: Please add some of your code with a minimal, reproducible example to your question.

Comment: Hi Simon,<html>...<iframe style="top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%;src="javascript:&quot;<HTML></HTML>">
</iframe>#Document <html>  <div id="WIN_0_1000000161" arid="1000000161" artype="Char"  "">
</div> </iframe></html>...</html>so here I want to traverse from ifreame to div id 1000000161

Comment: Add your code **to your question**. Edit the question, don't put code in the comments.

Comment: You won't be able to access the DOM of the iframe from the DOM of the parent document using XPath AFAIK, since they are two separate documents. The HTML doesn't make much sense in any case, since it should go `</html></iframe> ... </html>`...